# Choose value relating to index in render function, React Native, ES6

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, expo

I have a simple video view and all I want to do is assign the volume props to a number however it's an array of videos and each video has a different volume, so I created an array based on the index of videos now I need each video to have it's specific volume

```
var arr = [{vol: 1}, {vol: 3}, {vol: 8}]   //3 items in render
this.state = {
  volVid: arr
}

render() {
      return this.props.otherUsers.map(others =>
        <View key={others.infinite}>
          <Video
           volume={this.state.volVid}
          >
          </Video>
        </View>
      );
}
```

I would have put a function inside the volume props however it gave an error of expecting a number and instead receiving a function, so is there a way to reach into the array and pull the specific video volume?
Expo video component being used here.

Comment: check out the arguments that [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Syntax) passes to the callback function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code provided, you can just add the index to the passed callback function and use that. So:

```
render() {
  return this.props.otherUsers.map((others, index) =>
    <View key={others.infinite}>
      <Video
       volume={(this.state.volVid[index]) ? this.state.volVid[index].vol : 1}
      >
      </Video>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Added a ternary check just in case `otherUsers.length > arr.length`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is to refer to your `volVid` array through *index* prop on `.map()`:

```
render() {
  return this.props.otherUsers.map((others, index) => {
    <View key={others.infinite}>
      <Video
        volume={this.state.volVid[index].vol}
      >
      </Video>
    </View>
  });
}
```